# Yet another event dispatcher in c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, event-handling

I've written an event dispatcher for a private project which task is to collect events from different threads and dispatch them in a single thread:

```
namespace events
{
namespace
{
// unfortunately make_unique is not part of c++11 so we use our own
template <typename T, typename... Args>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args &&... args)
{
  return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
}

// Dispatcher for events posted from arbitrary threads
// Users can register functions that listen for certain events. When such events are posted from
// arbitary threads, a single dispatcher thread will sequentially call the registered callbacks.
template <typename BaseEvent>
class dispatcher
{
public:
  dispatcher() : running_(false), ready_(false) {}
  // non copyable
  dispatcher(dispatcher const &) = delete;
  dispatcher &operator=(dispatcher) = delete;
  // but movable
  dispatcher(dispatcher &&) = default;

  // Needs to be called once for dispatching to start
  // It is possible to register callbacks and post events before this function has been called
  void start()
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    running_ = true;
    thread_ = make_unique<std::thread>(&dispatcher<BaseEvent>::worker, this);
    // do not return until thread is ready for processing events
    condition_.wait(lock, [this]() { return !ready_; });
  }

  // Stops processing of events and joins dispatching thread
  // Depending on timing, events already queued may still be executed. The queue is not cleared
  // after stopping, so it is possible to use stop()/start() sequences to pause execution
  // After stop() returns it is ensured that no callbacks will be executed
  void stop()
  {
    {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
      running_ = false;
    }
    condition_.notify_one();
    thread_->join();
  }

  using callback_t = std::function<void(BaseEvent const &)>;

  // Register a function as an event listener
  // It is allowed to register multiple callbacks for the same event id
  void register_event(int event_id, callback_t function)
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    callbacks_.insert(std::make_pair(event_id, std::move(function)));
  }

  // Post event for immediate execution
  template <typename Event>
  void post(int event_id, Event ev)
  {
    post_delayed_until(event_id, std::move(ev), std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now());
  }

  // Post event for delayed execution
  template <typename Event, typename Duration>
  void post_delayed_for(int event_id, Event ev, Duration const &duration)
  {
    post_delayed_until(event_id, std::move(ev),
                       std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() + duration);
  }

  // Post event for delayed execution
  template <typename Event, typename TimePoint>
  void post_delayed_until(int event_id, Event ev, TimePoint time_point)
  {
    {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
      events_.insert(std::make_pair(std::move(time_point),
                                    std::bind(&dispatcher<BaseEvent>::defer<Event>, this, event_id,
                                              std::move(ev), std::placeholders::_1)));
    }
    condition_.notify_one();
  }

private:
  // dispatcher working thread
  void worker()
  {
    bool wait_delayed = false;
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> wait_until;

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);

    // signal start() function that we are ready for processing
    ready_ = true;
    condition_.notify_one();

    while (running_)
    {
      // step through the event queue, since we are giving up our lock during callback execution we
      // cannot rely on it being valid after that which makes traversing a little more complicated
      auto it = events_.begin();
      while (running_ && it != events_.end())
      {
        // our event queue is sorted for execution timestamps, so we can stop iterating once we hit
        // an event in the future
        if (it->first > std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now())
        {
          wait_delayed = true;
          wait_until = it->first;
          break;
        }

        auto function = it->second;
        events_.erase(it);

        // giving up lock here!
        function(lock);

        it = events_.begin();
      }

      // spurious interrupts are okay here; if the queue is still empty we will just return to sleep
      if (wait_delayed)
      {
        condition_.wait_until(lock, wait_until);
        wait_delayed = false;
      }
      else
      {
        condition_.wait(lock);
      }
    }
  }

  // wrapper around callback function
  template <typename Event>
  void defer(int event_id, Event ev, std::unique_lock<std::mutex> &lock)
  {
    // because we unlock the mutex during callbacks and the callbacks map may change, we must make
    // a copy of the functions we need to call
    auto range = callbacks_.equal_range(event_id);
    std::vector<callback_t> functions;
    for (auto it = range.first; it != range.second; ++it)
    {
      functions.push_back(it->second);
    }

    // since we made a copy of the callback list we can now process all registered callbacks in one
    // batch without mutex lock
    lock.unlock();
    for (auto &function : functions)
    {
      function(ev);
    }
    lock.lock();
  }

  bool running_;
  bool ready_;

  std::unique_ptr<std::thread> thread_;
  std::mutex mutex_;
  std::condition_variable condition_;

  std::multimap<int, callback_t> callbacks_;

  using defer_t = std::function<void(std::unique_lock<std::mutex> &)>;
  std::multimap<std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock>, defer_t> events_;
};
}
```

I'm trying to make the dispatcher as user friendly as possible. What I am still unhappy with so far, is that you have to use a base event structure for passing data. By far cooler would be to pass in arbitrary argument lists in post, but I have not found a way so far to make it possible.

Anyway, all kind of feedback is appreciated!

Here is a usage example:

```
struct event
{
  events::dispatcher<event> &dispatcher;
  static int const id = 0;
};

int main()
{
  events::dispatcher<event> dispatcher;

  dispatcher.register_event(event::id, [](event const &e) {
    std::cout << "timer event occured\n";
    e.dispatcher.post_delayed_for(event::id, e, std::chrono::seconds(1));
  });

  dispatcher.start();

  event e{dispatcher};
  dispatcher.post_delayed_for(event::id, std::move(e), std::chrono::seconds(1));

  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));

  dispatcher.stop();

  return 0;
}
```

And here is a snippet of what I'd imagine the usage to be ideally:

```
int main()
{
  events::dispatcher dispatcher;

  dispatcher.register_event(EVENT_SAMPLE, [](int a) {
    std::cout << "received event: " << a << "\n";
  });

  dispatcher.start();
  dispatcher.post(EVENT_SAMPLE, 42);
  dispatcher.stop();

  return 0;
}
```

But I cannot find a way to allow different signatures for events while remaining type safe. I have posted a sample trying something like that [on ideone](http://ideone.com/Obya2u), but it has some serious problems: dependent on RTTI, detects validity of posts at runtime instead of at compile time, and it does not properly detect lambdas, since there is no implicit conversion when looking for template matches.

When further overthinking this, it makes sense though, since people could register events with different function signatures, and I wouldn't know how to handle that, but allowing multiple functions to be registered to one event is important to me. So I guess I'll drop the idea and roll with the event structure.

Comment: Welcome to CR. Interesting question.

Comment: Note: the arguments to `start()` were originally there to allow different thread implementations (std::thread was a template argument then) but I dropped that for simplicity and the arguments were forgotten. I'll leave them in here to not mutilate the original post :-)

Comment: it's ok to modify the code *before* you've received an answer. We just don't want good answers invalidated. Sometimes it's useful to know *why* communities have arcane rules. =)

Comment: @RubberDuck thanks for the hint; i've corrected the code accordingly

Comment: Why is the `thread` behind a `unique_ptr`?

Comment: When you write "pass in arbitrary argument lists in post" what do you mean more precisely? What would then be passed to the callbacks? Because if you're looking to be able to do e.g. `dispatcher<int, int>` and having the post and then later the callback functions receive two integers, the answer - I think - is simply making `dispatch` a variadic class template. BTW: I think you should be using steady_clock instead of high_resolution_clock. Without having analyzed the code in detail you probably need your clock to be monotonic.

Comment: @Veedrac good point. I should use std::thread directly.

Comment: @user786653 I've updated my post with snippets of usage, and pseudo code of usage as I'd imagine it ideally. Also why do you think I should be using a monotonic clock?

Comment: @nijansen: If the clock isn't monotonic it can jump backwards and forwards (if it's tied to the system clock for example, it can jump days/years between calls to `now`). Also your idea might work if you have some kind of traits class for events that users have to register, so you'll know the expected signature at compile time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Start/Stop

You should consider calling these from your constructor/destructor so that the thread is ready when constructed and automatically stopped when destroyed. It would make is easier to use. Ask yourself this, would you ever create a dispatcher without the intent of calling `start()`/`stop()` on it? If not, they should be called from your ctor/dtor.

## `ready_` is redundant

In `start` you can simply wait for `running_` to be true and remove `ready_`. That said I don't really think that there is a need to wait for the thread to have started... You could just return without waiting as the events will be executed as soon as the thread is up. Yes, sure you may have a very slight delay before your events start executing, but you may have that even if the thread is already up because the OS doesn't guarantee that your thread will be scheduled immediately.

## Skip `unique_ptr` on `thread`

As has already been mentioned as you have disallowed copy/move I would recommend that you just have the thread as a member in the class without the `unique_ptr`. The thread is default constructed as an empty thread object without an associated thread.

## Better naming

As `mutex_`  is protecting `events_` it should probably be called `events_lock_` or something similar. Same goes for `condition_`.

## Simplify loop logic

The loop in your worker seems a bit convoluted I would probably structure it something like this (caveat-emptor: I might have changed behaviour on shutdown):

```
while (running_) {
    auto next_event = std::chrono::time_point::max(); 
    if(!events.empty()){
        next_event = events.begin()->first;
    }

    // Will wait until:
    // 1) the time of the next event OR 
    // 2) the thread was notified AND
    //    a) The thread is set to terminate OR
    //    b) A event with a closer time point was detected
    //       at which point we re-calculate the sleep time.
    condition_.wait_until(lock, next_event, [&](){
            return !running ||
                   (!events.empty() && events.begin()->first < next_event);
        });

    // Woken up either through notify of new events, or because it is time
    // for the next event.
    if(next_event <= std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()){
         // Note that here events is never empty because otherwise
         // next_event would be end of time and we would not enter here.
         // Only place where events are removed is below. 
         auto it = events.begin();
         auto func = it->second;
         events.erase(it);
         func(lock); // Temporarily releases lock
    }
}
```

## Use standard functions/methods

I would change:

```
auto range = callbacks_.equal_range(event_id);
std::vector<callback_t> functions;
for (auto it = range.first; it != range.second; ++it)
{
  functions.push_back(it->second);
}
```

to:

```
auto range = callbacks_.equal_range(event_id);
std::vector<callback_t> functions();
std::transform(range.first, range.second, std::back_inserter(functions), 
    [](auto& p){ return p->second; });
```

## Use `std::atomic`

Signalling variables such as `running_` and `ready_` typically are implemented using atomic types. This means that you do not need to take a mutex lock to read/write to them.

## Suffix `_t` is reserved for use by POSIX.

If you're not on a POSIX system then you're safe. For more info, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/2498188).

Comment: "Start/Stop" "You should consider just making these into your constructor/destructor." → But `stop`-`start` pairs are intended to be called to "pause" the thread, so that doesn't really work.

Comment: Very nice findings! Is type_t really also reserved when not in the global namespace? I doubt that Posix will ever place something in an events::dispatcher namespace.

Comment: @nijansen to the best of my knowledge, POSIX is not aware of namespaces and the identifiers are just reserved anywhere (they may use them in macros for example).

Comment: While implementing the points you mention, some questions came up: while your worker loop is a lot simpler than mine, doesn't it lead to a busy loop when only events are in the queue with timestamps in the future? Since the predicate is checked first from my understanding, there will be no waiting if the queue is not empty, correct? Also I can't just use `std::vector<callback_t>(range.first, range.second)` since they are of type `std::pair<int, callback_t>`, so I do still need my loop?

Comment: @nijansen I fixed the answer, hopefully fixed all the issues :)

Answer (score 2):

Some small thoughts here.

`thread_`, as mentioned in the comments, should probably not be behind a pointer. This removes the need for the local `make_unique` entirely.

`lock_` is a poor name for a lock; *what* is it locking? What logical invariant does it hold?

`start` and `stop` aren't seem thread-safe relative to each other. What is callable concurrently should be well documented, which is lacking here.

`running_` seems like it could just be an `atomic_flag`. Those are normally simpler than locking, so I'd prefer it.

`condition_.wait(lock, [this]() { return !ready_; });` seems like it should be `condition_.wait(lock, [this]() { return ready_; });` as `condition_.wait(lock, pred)` acts like

```
while (!pred()) wait(lck);
```

and you seem to want

```
while (!ready_) wait(lck);
```

instead of

```
while (!!ready_) wait(lck);
```

I don't like that you're reusing `condition_` for two things and haven't explained why they can't interfere. Heck, when dealing with locks very little matters *except* for the explanation of why you think things should work.

I don't get

```
if (wait_delayed)
{
  condition_.wait_until(lock, wait_until);
  wait_delayed = false;
}
else
{
  condition_.wait(lock);
}
```

as `wait_until` is *weaker* than `wait`, so it's hard to say you've *delayed* anything. Delaying would be more like

```
sleep_until(wait_until);
condition_.wait(lock);
```

This is also odd:

```
if (it->first > std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now())
{
  wait_delayed = true;
  wait_until = it->first;
  break;
}
```

given you just use the last `wait_until`, rather than, say, the maximum.

Comment: Concerning the `wait_until`: The logic here is that we find the first event that is supposed to happen in the future and remember the time it should be executed. Since maps are sorted by key, it's sufficient to find the first one. Then, if we found an event that is supposed to be executed in the future, wait for further events, but at most until the event we found is due. If no event is queued for future execution we can wait until a new event is posted (no need for `wait_until` here). If I have a logic mistake here please let me know! Besides that you bring up some good points.

Comment: @nijansen My problem isn't the logic, it's the fact the variable names suggest you're doing something else entirely.